# Selecting file path-string returns empty N1QL query

Tags: java, sql, couchbase, sql++

Given the following code:

```
String statement = "SELECT path FROM test-bucket;";
N1qlQueryResult queryResult = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(statement);

for (N1qlQueryRow n1qlQueryRow : queryResult) {
  System.out.println(n1qlQueryRow.toString());
}
```

And the test-bucket on Couchbase containing only JSON-files structured like the following example:

```
{
 "path": "C:\\some\\path\\filename.txt",
 "dateCreation": "Dec 11, 2015 6:39:22 PM",
}
```

I want to print the `path` .
However this does not work, because the `queryResult` is empty after running the code. If I change the `statement` to `"SELECT dateCreation FROM test-bucket"` everything works fine. What I have to do to print out the `path` ?

Comment: Try SELECT \`path\` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround `path` with combining grave accent.

```
String statement = "SELECT `path` FROM test-bucket;";
```